# Firebase Connection manager should return only one result

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am following documentation located at: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-connection-state

However, my implementation and test of:

```
        connectionCheck.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            let connected = snapshot.value as? Bool
            if connected != nil && connected! {
                print("Connected")
            } else {
                print("Not connected")
            }
        })
```

The output in Xcode notes:

```
Not connected
Connected
```

If however I turn off the wifi, the result is simply:

```
Not connected
```

Given I wish to allow actions to occur and present to the user if there is not a connection, how can I ensure that this Firebase listener only returns the correct response once?

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, you may want to add some additional functionality;

If you want to know about the users connection to Firebase, you should observe the .info/connected path, as stated in the docs.

The design pattern I use is to set up a global app variable called isConnected, and attach a Firebase observer to the .info/connected path.

Then in my app wherever I need to know if the user is connected or not, I attach a KVO Observer to my global isConnected var.

When the user disconnects (or connects), the Firebase observer is called which sets isConnected = false (or true).

Then, any places in my app that are observing the isConnected var is notified of the disconnect/connect and can take appropriate action.

Here's the code

```
let connectedRef = rootRef.childByAppendingPath(".info/connected")

connectedRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

  self.isConnected = snapshot.value as! Bool //KVO property

        //this is just so you can see it's being set, remove
        if ( self.isConnected == true ) {
            print("connected")
        } else {
            print("not connected")
        }
        // testing code
})
```